# trying to write a code that can compress a video in small size using yovenny/VideoCompress

Tags: java, android, compression

It's been two days since I am trying to get code an activity in which a video can be compressed into small size video files like WhatsApp. I have tried all the solutions that I have found on the internet but none of these workers maybe I have used them in the wrong way at present I have a solution in https://github.com/yovenny/VideoCompress so I have tried to work with that still I get some error. The error says that

```
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nanb.alpha-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nanb.alpha-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libcompress.so"
```

if you have some other solution then please share with me and tell me how to implement the solution in my applictaion. the code is been given bellow.

```
 public class videocompress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    return MediaController.getInstance().convertVideo(params[0],params[1]);
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean compressed) {
    super.onPostExecute(compressed);
    if(compressed){
        Log.d("video compress","Compression successfully!");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use [SiliCompressor](https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor)

Here is some example code:

Video Compression Class

```
class VideoCompressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

Context mContext;
String thumbnail;

public VideoCompressAsyncTask(Context context, String thumbnail){
mContext = context;
this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
pd.setMessage("Uploading Video...");
pd.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... paths) {
String filePath = null;
try {

filePath = SiliCompressor.with(mContext).compressVideo(paths[0], paths[1]);

} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return filePath;

}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String compressedFilePath) {
super.onPostExecute(compressedFilePath);
UploadMedia(compressedFilePath, thumbnail,"video");
Log.i("Silicompressor", "Path: "+compressedFilePath);
}
}
```

and in `onActivityResult` you call this class

```
if(requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
Uri uri = data.getData();
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
if(cursor!=null) {
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getPackageName() + "/media/videos");
if (f.mkdirs() || f.isDirectory())
//compress and output new video specs
new VideoCompressAsyncTask(this,getThumbnailPathForLocalFile(this,uri)).execute(cursor.getString(column_index), f.getPath());
cursor.close();
}else
Toast.makeText(ChatScreen.this, "No Video Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

also you can get video thumbnail via this method

```
public static String getThumbnailPathForLocalFile(ChatScreen context, Uri fileUri ) {
    long fileId = getFileId(context, fileUri);
    Log.e("ID",fileId+"");
    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(),
            fileId, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
    Cursor thumbCursor = null;
    try {
        thumbCursor = context.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, thumbColumns, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID + " = " + fileId, null, null);
        if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA));
            Log.e("ThumbPath",thumbPath);
            return thumbPath;
        }

    } finally {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but dint work no file is been created and temp file methods are not found